# HTTP-Headers in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway in version 3.1.6.
Some of my backend servers, which are proxied through the gateway, provide binary http streams. This works fine as long as the backend provides the first chunk immediately, but some of them needs some minutes or more (some do never provide any data and this is wanted and by intention) for the first chunk. Therefore those servers send the first response header before the data is available. This is working fine as long as I connect directly to those servers, it is also working fine when I connect through an NGINX-Proxy, but not when I use Spring Cloud Gateway.
So is there any kind of possibility to flush those headers?

Edit 1:
The header such a service provides and I directly want have forwarded is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/x-protobuf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 11 May 2023 08:59:29 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Connection: keep-alive
```

Best Regards

Torben

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to take a look on filters :

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/

This is an example of a filter :

https://spring.io/blog/2022/08/26/creating-a-custom-spring-cloud-gateway-filter

Comment: How do you mean it? I do not want to change the Header, filter anything or change the responses. I use spring cloud gateway the more the less as a proxy. I do not need to change or filter responses. The reason why I use it and not an nginx, is, because it is possible to define routes to be proxied programmatically and during runtime (e.g. by calling a service registry).